# Setup ftp-client in php-html5 netbeans 8.0.1

Tags: ftp-client, netbeans-8

I just donwloaded and installed Netbeans 8.0.1 for building my websites. The specs state that an ftp-client is included.

However after searching within netbeans and online I can not find how to set it up.

Could somebody point out to me where the ftp client is located within netbeans?

Thx,

Comment: I got the same problem, how to upload/download to a server like an other PHP project. did you find a solution ?